# Trigger an event when a new certificate is added to certificate store

Tags: windows, x509certificate, cryptoapi, certificate-store

I am writing a windows service which can be triggered whenever a new certificate is added to the MY certificate store. It then opens the certificate store through this service and carries out some actions.

Is there a way to implement a callback function in the service/application which can be called by the crypto APIs when applications like mmc.exe or certreq.exe request and install a new certificate in the certificate store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an alternative. MY cert store certificates are written in

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates

Now using a directory event watcher to view newly installed certificates.